# Accessing properties of a Swift class conforming to CustomNSError from Objective-C results in a crash

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a class conforming to CustomNSError which looks like this:

```
class ErrorConformingToCustomNSError: NSObject, CustomNSError
{
    public static let errorDomain: String = "SomeErrorDomain"
    public var errorCode: Int { return self.code }
    public var errorUserInfo: [String : Any] { return [:] }

    let property: String = "I'm a property of the CustomNSError"
}
```

It gets thrown from a Swift library, but I'm catching it in a legacy app written in Objective-C. From the app, for debugging purposes, I want to print some properties of the error object:

```
NSError* error = nil;
[SomeClass methodThrowingCustomNSError:&error];
ErrorConformingToCustomNSError* castedError = (ErrorConformingToCustomNSError*)error;

NSLog(@"%@", castedError.property);
```

When the NSLog is executed, instead of getting a print statement, I get an unrecognized selector error:

> 2017-04-18 15:59:54.211051 errortest[47443:314797] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftNativeNSError property]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100b03810'

If I subclass `NSError` instead of conforming to `CustomNSError`, everything seems to work correctly. [Here is a gist showing the two scenarios](https://gist.github.com/evl5051/2b7c6aa372c840fbfec2c25700410bfc) - you can paste into a new MacOS project and see the crash. I am on Xcode version 8.3.

Have I run into a language bug, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: In the gist your swift class `ErrorConformingToCustomNSError` the `property` are not public. In general to access swift classes and properties in Objective-C, they need to be public. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @Ad-J Just tried running the project again with `public let property`, no dice. Getting the same old `NSInvalidArgumentException`.